# How to enable cookies acceptance in WKWebView in ios

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have a native iOS app with WKWebView. Since i'm facing a session lost issue in iOS App. While app is idle for a long time. And i try to use it. I lost all session in my WKWebView.
I hope cookies are lost , so session is lost.
There is any way to solve this session lost is WkWebView.